# Docker charm on juju

Tags: juju, maas, docker

Ubuntu 18.04

Why I get this error, how can I fix it?

Could not add requested charm. Server responded with: cannot retrieve charm "cs:trusty/docker-8": cannot get archive: Get https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/trusty/docker-8/archive: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

All my servers are behind proxy, And I needed to add all Proxy related certificate to that specific node which I ma trying to deploy charm, using this command:

Obtain the certificate(s) in Base64 encoded X.509 format.

    1. Copy them to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

    2. If the extension is not .crt rename the files. 

    3. sudo update-ca-certificates